# How to remove escape character from json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm converting a List to json. I tried with both method json.encode() and jsonEncode() it converts to json but it shows escaped character like :

`[{\"label\":\"name\",\"field_type\":\"text\",\"option\":[]}]`

I have tried all regex and replace method but escaped character not removed. But I print the json it it showing proper format.

`[{"label":"name","field_type":"text","option":[]}]`

How can I remove the escape character in flutter.

Comment: Please stop misusing the quote formatting (which you appear to be doing all the time in your questions) - that is for when you are actually quoting someone or something.

Comment: Where does it show the escaped characters? Please show your code. If you want to hardcode a json string in your code for example then escaping is the right thing to do (or define it as raw string)

Comment: when I encode the json using json.encode() it shows escaped character

Comment: "it shows" is very vague. Where and how does it show that? Maybe give us some code to reproduce it